# NLTK Chunking Error

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, chunking

I'm trying to implement a sentence chunker based on a Maxent Classifier, as described in the NLTK book (Example 7.9):

http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch07.html#code-classifier-chunker

When I try to evaluate the chunker with

```
chunker = ConsecutiveNPChunker(train_sents)
print chunker.evaluate(test_sents)
```

or to chunk a sentence with

```
print chunker.parse(test_sents[1])
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    print chunker.parse(test_sents[1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/api.py", line 34, in parse
    assert 0, "ChunkParserI is an abstract interface"
AssertionError: ChunkParserI is an abstract interface
```

I didn't find anything on google and I'm stuck on this point. Any help would be really useful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You evidently haven't implemented your chunker yet. "ChunkParserI is an abstract interface" means that you need to derive a class from it and define your own `parse()` method. The NLTK chapter you link to shows how to define an example class, `ConsecutiveNPChunker`.

The final step will be to create an instance of your new class and call its `eval()` method (which it inherits from `ChunkParserI`, so you don't to provide a replacement).

Comment: Thanks Alexis. I actually instantiate my class as follows:
chunker = ConsecutiveNPChunker(train_sents)
I edited the original question to make it clear.

Comment: But you don't make clear how `ConsecutiveNPChunker` is defined. Obviously it does not provide a `parse` method.

Comment: Sorry for not adding the ConsecutiveNPChunker definition, I didn't add it because it's a bit lengthy. But the link I provide has the exact class which includes a parse() method

Comment: The example in the NLTK book adds a `parse` method, and it works. You don't, so you get the `parse`  from `chunk/api.py`, whose only job is to raise the error. Perhaps you have an indentation error in your code?

Comment: Thanks! Indentation was wrong so - as you said - the parse() from chunk/api.py was called instead the one from the ConsecutiveNPChunker ...

Comment: Good to hear. Just to be clear: Because of your indentation error,  `ConsecutiveNPChunker` did not HAVE a `parse` method, which is why the method of the parent class was called.

Comment: @vasilis would it be possible for you to post the full code you used to get this to work? I'm having a similar error and I don't understand how to fix.

Comment: @user, fix your indentation or write a `parse()` method, whichever the case may be.